# Get the width and height of an element, and making it a javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I have a canvas snow script with the width & height varibles set to the window innerWidth and innerHeight. I need to change the variable to the width and height of an existing element with the class `.featured-image-link`.

Here is part of the existing code I need to change:

```
var w,h;
w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

and

```
function clientResize(ev){
    w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};
window.addEventListener("resize", clientResize);
```

I googled this before asking here, but all I could get was how to change the width & height, not setting it to the width and height of an existing element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can select your element with `document.querySelector(".featured-image-link")` and then you can access its size with `.clientWidth` and `.clientHeight`.

So you can do:

```js
var el = document.querySelector(".featured-image-link");
var w,h;
w = canvas.width = el.clientWidth;
h = canvas.height = el.clientHeight;
```